# How to solve Index 7 out of bounds for length 7 in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Weirdly, I've been getting the following error message in Kotlin while working with list in another function:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:4164)
    at MainKt.findNumIndex(main.kt:19)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:9)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt)
```

The code I was working was the following:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf<Int>(3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 7)
    println("The list looks like the following: $list")

    println("Search for this number:")
    var searchNum = readLine()?.toInt()

    if(searchNum != null) {
        val index = findNumIndex(list, searchNum)
        println("The index of $searchNum is $index")
    }

}

fun findNumIndex(list: List<Int>, searchNum: Int): Int {
    var indexPosition: Int = 0

    for(i in list) {
        if(list[i] == searchNum) {
            indexPosition = i
        } else {
            indexPosition = -1
        }
    }

    return indexPosition
}
```

Basically, I was working on a program in which you give a number whose index you want to find from a list

Comment: Lists are indexed starting at 0. Your list with 7 members is indexed 0 to 6, there is no index 7

Comment: With this line `for(i in list)` you do not get the index. You get the item.

Comment: Ohh, so you mean that ``` for(i in list) ``` gives me the value and not index number?

Comment: Yes. You can also just use list.forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's best to avoid counting list indices manually if possible, to avoid off-by-one and other easily introduced errors.

Kotlin has many helpful functions to do things like this, including one to do exactly what you want: [`indexOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of.html):

```
val index = list.indexOf(searchNum)
```

---

To answer your actual question, if you want to manually loop over the indices rather than the elements, you can use `for(i in list.indices)`. You also should return as soon as you find the index, otherwise you will continue the loop after you've found it and end up returning `-1` anyway:

```
fun findNumIndex(list: List<Int>, searchNum: Int): Int {
    for(i in list.indices) {
        if(list[i] == searchNum) {
            return i
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```kotlin
for(i in list) {
        if(list[i] == searchNum) {
```

`i` is the element of list, not current index. Eventually you read the last value (which is 7) and run out of bounds. If you put, say, `100` in the beginning like:

```kotlin
val list = listOf<Int>(100, 3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 7)
```

You will get `Index 100 out of bounds for length 8`.

To iterate over a collection with indices you need:

```kotlin
for((index, value) in someCollection.withIndex()) {
    // do something
}
```